# Как работает контекстный менеджер в ПИТОНЕ

Tags: python, python-import

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def nullresource(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
        yield None
    except:
        pass

class NullResource():
    def __enter__(self):
        return None
    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return True

with nullresource() as r:
    r.some_method()

with NullResource() as r:
    r.some_method()
```

Не понимаю как работает контекстный менеджер. Можете объяснить, как исполнится пример кода и почему именно так?

Comment: "как исполнится пример кода" - запустите и посмотрите что будет, а потом задайте конкретный вопрос, что именно вам непонятно

Answer (score 1):

`yeild` прерывает функцию возвращая значение None. Эта часть аналог `__enter__`, тутошнее `None` присваивается к `r`.

Потом выполняется тело блока with. В этой  Там возникает ошибка `None object has no attribute 'some_method'` потому что some_method нигде не определен.

Это исключение попадает в блок `except` и там игнорируется.

Во втором случае `__enter__` присваивает значение r, а `__exit__` выполняется при выходе из блока `with`.

Исключение возникшее в блоке передается в метод  `.__exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)` в аргументах и там никак не обрабатывется в вашем случае.

Правильный код:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def nullresource(*args, **kwargs):
    def somemethod():
        print('somemethod')
    try:
        yield somemethod
    except Exception as e:
        print('произошла непредвиденная ошибка')
        raise e

with nullresource() as r_some_method:
    r_some_method()
```

и с классом

```
class NullResource():
    def some_method(self):
        print('NullResource().some_method()')

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if exc_type:
            print('произошла непредвиденная ошибка')

with NullResource() as r:
    r.some_method()
```

Comment: да, можно убрать